# Reading string and integer on the same line

Tags: c++, io

I have a datafile to be read, it has something like this

john  1  2  3  4

I want to read these data and perform some functions, just want to make sure I'm doing this right.

```
while(myIn.peek()!=EOF)
{
getline(myIn, name, '/n');
myIn>>a>>b>>c>>d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will screw up if the next character is not the end-of-file yet there's a failure in the extraction. This often happens at the end of files where there's an extra `\n` before the end.

You also have a problem with your call to `getline`. `/n` is a multibyte character. Presumably you meant `\n`, but even then, there's no `\n` after "john" in the line. Instead, just use `myIn >> name`.

Anyway, it's more idiomatic to use your extractions as the `while` condition. Try this:

```
while (myIn >> name >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
  // Do something with them
}
```

The body of the `while` loop simply won't execute if any of the extractions fail. That means you can quickly get out before doing any more damage. However, here we don't actually care whether each set of values is on a separate line or not. It would happily accept:

```
john 1 2 3 4 mary 5 6 7 8
```

An alternative is to read the whole line with `std::getline` first and then you can parse the line:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(myIn, line)) {
  std::stringstream line_stream(line);
  if (line_stream >> name >> a >> b >> c >> d) {
    // Do something with this line
  }
}
```

Now, even if a line is badly formatted, you'll still move on to the next line instead of giving up all together.

Comment: well, the data file has multiple lines with the same structure, I want to read one line, perform some functions, and then go on to the next line. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JasonLee Then perhaps you'll prefer the second option. I like it when I'm doing line by line processing.